# How to create extra SUB ARCHIVE for each page?

Tags: slug

How to add slug structure for pages like this:

1. /page_1_name/doctors/ -> load doctors taxonomy for this page slug
   /page_1_name/prices/ -> load prices taxonomy for this page slug
2. /page_2_name/doctors/
   /page_2_name/prices/

etc.

Interesting how to add this slug functionality globally for all pages.

Answer (score -1):

Solution was add slug via add_rewrite_rule()

Comment: If you're going to post an answer then actual code that resolved your issue would be more useful to future visitors.